# Getting Dropdown values outside of BeginForm, and using those values to populate TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two drop downs outside of the BeginForm.  I need to grab those values and add them into the TextBoxFor, so I can pass those values into my controller.

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedProductID, Model.ProductList, new { @id = "ProductList", @class = "product_list" })

     @using (Html.BeginForm("Cart", "Home", FormMethod.Post))}
        {

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Product,new { value ="*<need the select ddl value>*", @class = "hidden" }))
.... other stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event of the dropdown, get the value of selected item, set that on the textbox. simnple !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

   $("#SelectedProductID").change(function(e){
      var selectedValue=$(this).val();
      $("#Product").val(selectedValue);
   });

});
</script>
```

Assuming you have jQuery library included in the page.

Comment: I do have jQuery. I was hoping for a way without jQuery. 
I guess this is the only way without page load. Thanks!